# Removing outlet with 3 sets of wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I have 3 conduits (1 2 3), each with a set of black B, white W, and ground G wires. They were previously connected to an duplex outlet I want to remove. The duplex outlet have 2 screws each side (L and R) and a ground screw.

1B and 2B are connected to the top L screw
3B is connected to the bottom L screw

1W and 2W are connected to the top R screw
3W is connected to the bottom R screw

1G, 2G, and 3G are connected to the ground screw.

After disconnecting the three room have no power. What should I do to restore power? Should I connect all black together in one bundle and all white together in another bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, The two screws on each side of the outlet connect to the same piece of metal so, in essence,connected to the same point if the tabs between them are intact. You need to connect the three black wires together and the three white wires together. You can then get a cover to cover the junction box but the box must remain accessible, can't be covered over with plaster, drywall, etc. Don't forget to connect the ground wires together too.

Answer (score 2):

### Code rules

Notice how removing the receptacle severed the hot and neutral wires, but it did not sever the ground wire.  That is on purpose.

Code requires receptacles in certain locations.  Generally within 6' of linear wall anywhere someone might want to put a light (practically: every 12'), and on kitchen countertops within 2' of anywhere someone might put a kitchen appliance. That corresponds to the length of typical cords.  **It is illegal to remove receptacles which are required**.  This will bite you when you sell the house and the inspector sees missing receptacles.

As Jack describes, Code requires that all wires end inside junction boxes, and the *junction box covers* be accessible forever without needing tools or disassembling any part of the building or its finish.  **It is illegal to "bury" junction boxes behind wall coverings or built-in cabinets or trim**. The only option in that case is to utterly destroy both ends of all cables going to that box so they can never be energized by accident, and then bypass the box altogether with new cable.  There is not a way to bury a splice for remodeling. (it would be impossible to access for troubleshooting or maintenance).

If you have built-in cabinets or the like about to cover the box, there are ways of having the box come through the built-ins.

### The receptacle was a splice, too.

The receptacle was performing a double duty as both an outlet and a splice block.  When you removed the receptacle, it stopped being a splice, and so the wires did what - did you cap off all 6 individually? Leave them bare and flapping around?

If your change will conform to all the above rules, you can splice the 3 black wires together, splice the 3 white wires together, and install a blank junction box cover plate.  That should restore the now-down circuits.

By "splice" I mean an approved method such as Wago lever-nuts, wire nuts, etc.